# Managing multiple files after Decompressing Tar.gz file In Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, tar, biztalk-2013, gzip, orchestration

I have to imagine an interface that can decompress one tar.gz (ZIJA) file into 3 tar.gz files (ZIJB, ZIJC and ZIJD).

These three files has to be treated independantly during the orchestration as it is an asynchronous one (only one ZIJA.tar.gz and his siblings can be treated at a time).

If I don't make a corelation between my receives shape and my send shapes my ZIJA.tar.gz is decompressed into 3 files  (ZIJB, ZIJC and ZIJD) correctly but the orchestration is launched 3 times (Once for the sibling file). And I want only 1 use to manage the 3 files

The problem is when I receive the file through my custom pipeline to decompress the ZIJA file, I have only 1 file that is treated by my orchestration (the first one, ZIJB). The other are not treated at all.

Edit : Thank you guys for your answer but let me explain with more details.

The objective of this interface is to decompress twice in a row tar.gz files organised this way : ZIJA.Tar.gz containing 1 to 3 files (ZIJB.targz and/Or ZIJC.targz and/Or ZIJD.targz) which has to be decompress in respective and different folders.

Moreover, I have to keep the information of the first targz content in order to recompress the original file with exactly the same organisation.

Between decompressing and recompressing I call SAP to make a treatement and I have to wait the answer of sap to start the recompression step.

To conclude, I can't start an other first decompression step (of ZIJA.targz) until all the steps above are finished.

One ZIJA.targz at a time. (One instance, only)

Sum up : ZIJA.targz => decompression => 1 to 3 files => decompression of the files toward the right separate folders => Call Sap => answer of SAP with the new files => Recompression of the 1 to 3 files => recompression of the ZIJA.targz with the exact same content of the first one I have decompressed.

Comment: From your custom pipeline you generate 3 different IBaseMessages or only one with different IBaseMessagePart?

Comment: Have you considered executing the pipeline in your Orchestration.  That way you can process one at a time in the Orchestration.